# How to use google translate to translate website automatically using geoip

Tags: google-translate, geoip

I have been looking around the internet for a script which would use google translate api to translate a website automatically through a geoip script without the need of clicking translate button. Since google does provide a small div snippet which you can add to your website and then through a drop down menu you can choose the language and click translate and it translates the whole website.

the snippet is here
http://translate.google.com/translate_tools?hl=en&layout=1&eotf=1&sl=ru&tl=en

How can i integrate a geoip script along with the above snippet or there are also a couple of google translate scripts available on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Using geoip to determine user's language is not optimal way, because people may speak/prefer different language than the main language in their geographical location.

`Accept-Language` header sent by client is something you would like to use, but it's not available in javascript (at least in any standard way).

However, there's available `navigator.language` which tells us the language of browser UI. Though not ideal, this is very easy to implement:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://translate.google.com/translate?u=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, '')) + '&langpair=auto|' + navigator.language.split('-')[0];">Translate</a>
```

Comment: i tried this code but it didnt work as i am wanting it to be.

Comment: It didn't work at all or you want it to work without clicking a link?

Comment: I dont think it worked or maybe i did something wrong. I want it to work without clicking the link and not getting forwarded to a page where it says google translate.

Comment: Well, it was merely an example of implementation.